# Where should I instantiate my cart with PHPCart in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js

I'm making a simple shopping cart system using Laravel 5 and Vue.js. The user clicks the add to basket button and Vue sends an AJAX request to the cart controller. That part works fine.

The documentation for PHPCart shows how to add an item to the cart:

```
$cart = new Cart();

$cart->add([
    'id'       => 1001,
    'name'     => 'Skinny Jeans',
    'quantity' => 1,
    'price'    => 90
]);
```

My question is, where do I set up the `$cart` variable in my controller, such that it can be accessed by all the various add/remove/update methods that will need it?

Comment: Many possibilities. You can do an Dependency Injection with your cart as Singleton, so when you are asking Cart $cart in you method, you'll always have the same object.
You can set $this->cart = new Cart; in your constructor. You can use Session aswell. Highly depends on your needs. IMO I always use dependency injection and Singleton with Cart.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access from multiple methods on your controller the simplest way is to use dependency injection in the constructor of your controller.

```
protected $cart;

public function __construct(Cart $cart)
{
    $this->cart = $cart;
}
```

Then in your various controller methods you can simply access it like

`$this->cart->add()`